# no entiendo como es que esta formula da el siguiente resultado

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Estoy haciendo el siguiente ejercicio

Ratiorg got statues of different sizes as a present from CodeMaster for his birthday, each statue having an non-negative integer size. Since he likes to make things perfect, he wants to arrange them from smallest to largest so that each statue will be bigger than the previous one exactly by 1. He may need some additional statues to be able to accomplish that. Help him figure out the minimum number of additional statues needed.

For statues = [6, 2, 3, 8], the output should be

solution(statues) = 3

Básicamente lo que dice es que hay que saber con cuantas estatuas hay que rellenar para que el array quede escalonado ascendentemente

la solucion dice ser la siguiente

```js
Math.max(...statues) - Math.min(...statues) - statues.length + 1
```

pero como puede ser que en el ejemplo el output sea 3 si según yo

`Math.max(...statues)` es 8

`Math.min(...statues)` es 2

8-2 = 6

`statues.length + 1` es 5

6-5 = 1 no es 3...

si

Comment: El link que mandas no abre nada, toma una imagen si puedes a ver que aparece.

Comment: lo quite, en el link esta lo mismo que escribi en la consigna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá te he creado el snippet de la operación, para explicar que pasa.

El tema es solo el orden de las operaciones mentales que haces.
Max = 8
Min = 2
8 - 2 = 6
Y acá el error
Length + 1 = 4 + 1 = - 5 ... esto es incorrecto, por que el orden que continua es:
 `- Length + 1 = - 4 + 1`
Por lo que nos queda entonces: 8 - 2 - 4 + 1 = 3

```js
var statues = [6, 2, 3, 8];
var maxStatues = Math.max(6, 2, 3, 8);
document.write(maxStatues);
document.write("-");
var minStatues = Math.min(6, 2, 3, 8);
document.write(minStatues);
document.write("-");
document.write(statues.length);
document.write("+1");

let num = Math.max(6, 2, 3, 8) - Math.min(6, 2, 3, 8) - statues.length + 1;

document.write("=" + num);
```